# Range search in quadtree efficiency

Tags: c, algorithm, tree, computer-science, quadtree

I have an implementation of a point quadtree and rangesearch of that tree in C. My rangesearch returns the correct result but when I run it through valgrind, valgrind gets killed. I am using a recursive approach. I would like to make my rangesearch more efficient but most of my attempts seem to be overly complicated.

```
int qt_rangesearch(qt_node* root, double x, double y, double d){
  qt_node* temp = root;
  int count = 0;
  if (root == NULL){ return 0; }
  if (dist2(temp->x, temp->y, x, y) <= (d*d)){
    count = 1;
  }
  return (count + 
          qt_rangesearch(temp->ne, x, y, d) + 
          qt_rangesearch(temp->nw, x, y, d) + 
          qt_rangesearch(temp->se, x, y, d) + 
          qt_rangesearch(temp->sw, x, y, d) );
}
```

This is my simple approach which is slow but kills Valgrind. How do I make it more efficient? I assume something along the lines of if point x,y is to SW of current node and current node further than d away from x,y than do not continue rangesearch to NE of current  node.

Edit:

My distance function:

```
double dist2(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    return (x1 - x2)*(x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2)*(y1 - y2);
}
```

Comment: Why do you assign to `temp` and not use `root` directly? What does `dist2` look like?

Comment: I should have used root, but was in a habit of creating a temp pointer in every function. Should have same result though

Comment: You need to clarify what "valgrind gets killed" **means**. It is literally as non-informative as saying "it don't work". Provide log info reports from valgrind with your question, along with related source.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to always recurse to every child of the node, so you always visit every node of the quadtree. If for some reason you always have to visit every node, why bother with a quadtree? Why not just keep a vector of nodes?

Usually a quadtree pays off because you can work out that you don't need to recurse down through some children. Either from the way the quadtree is built or by keeping some sort of book-keeping information at each node you will know e.g. that everything below this node is within distance D of it, and you can work out from this that there can be no node beneath a given child that you are interested in, so you don't need to recurse down it.

One way to exclude nodes is to keep a bounding box for everything beneath that node and to work out that everything in that bounding box is at least d away from the query point.

Another way is to rewrite the triangle inequality d(a, c) <= d(a, b) + d(b, c) to d(a, b) >= |d(a, c) - d(b, c)| (you may need to assume that d(x, y) = d(y, x) as well) and use this to work out that everything beneath a given node must be >= d from the query point.